# How important is Audit Logging in a Standalone Application

Tags: audit, audit-trail

My experience are mostly in developing web applications and we do a lot of audit trails there.  Literally every table is audited.  I believe this is because user transactions are centralized to a server and they share the same table so it is important who did what.

But now I am assigned to a project developing a standalone application (specifically a mobile application with occasional server transactions).  Some are suggesting to add Audit logging but I am not sure what is the norm for standalone applications.  For those who have experiences, kindly share if you think it is mandatory or not.  I'm leaning towards NO (that it is not that important) because it will only increase resource consumption (and mobile  limited).  It may affect performance, stability and usability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well for the app itself it may not be so important, however having automated error logs can be very useful when you faced with an angry customer(s) and need to quickly debug the app. You can even have a special 'debug mode' to collect more info.

You should also log your server transactions, adding an extra query in the request won't really affect performance.